# Javascript error :Object doesn't support this property or method in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have javascript validation method, its working good in firefox, but its not working in IE browser.
I'm getting error as `Object doesn't support this property or method` .Please advise..

```
function validateChunk(s)
{
    return !!s.match(/^[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?$/);
}

function filterValid(v)
{
    return !v;
}

function testCases(str)
{
    var chunks = str.split(",");
    var validated = chunks.map(validateChunk);
    return (0 === validated.filter(filterValid).length);

}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't have `.map()` or `.filter()`.

You  can find code to fill in for them on the MDN site:

- `filter` — [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- `map` — [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Is your IE9 running as IE8/7?